# How to align div tag left and right extreme?

Tags: html, css

I have created chat app using socket.io but the messages from sender and receiver must by on extreme right and extreme left. How can I do that ? I have added the styles but the messages are not going one below the other instead they are going inline. How can I fix it ?

Code:

```
<div id="messages" className="card-block">
                            {this.state.messages.map((message, index) => {

                                let word = message.message.split('#')

                                if(word[0] === this.props.match.params.user){
                                    return (
                                        <div key={index} className="msgBoxRight"><p className="msgTextRight">{word[1]}</p></div>
                                    )
                                }else{
                                    return (
                                        <div key={index} className="msgBoxLeft"><p className="msgTextLeft">{word[1]}</p></div>
                                    ) 
                                }

                            })}
                        </div>
```

CSS:

```
#messages{
    height:300px;
    overflow: scroll;
    width: 100%;
}

.msgBoxRight {
    max-width: 350px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    float: right;
}

.msgTextRight {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #EBEEFD;
    border-radius: 25px;
}

.msgBoxLeft {
    max-width: 350px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    float: left;
}

.msgTextLeft {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #EBEEFD;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
```

Screenshot:
[image]

How it should display:

[image]

Comment: Try adding a <br> after every msgBoxRight/Left

Comment: @JSDEV Will it work ? if I add <br> after <p> tag ?

Comment: i'm not sure if it will work for your code...just give it a try

Comment: hi brother i have the same issue can you help me?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69615537/changing-class-name-dynamically-in-react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add **'clear:both'** to the elements you have **floated**, that is to classes **'.msgBoxRight'** and **'.msgBoxLeft'**.

```css
#messages {
  height: 300px;
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 100%;
}

.msgBoxRight {
  max-width: 350px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  float: right;
  clear: both;
}

.msgTextRight {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #EBEEFD;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.msgBoxLeft {
  max-width: 350px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}

.msgTextLeft {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #EBEEFD;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="messages" class="card-block">
  <div class="msgBoxRight">
    <p class="msgTextRight">hello Aditya</p>
  </div>
  <div class="msgBoxLeft">
    <p class="msgTextLeft">hello world</p>
  </div>
  <div class="msgBoxRight">
    <p class="msgTextRight">i am varun</p>
  </div>
   <div class="msgBoxLeft">
    <p class="msgTextLeft">i am Aditya</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Flexbox.
And I think you don't need the `div` wrappers.

```css
#messages {
  height: 300px;
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.msgTextRight,
.msgTextLeft {
  max-width: 350px;
  background-color: #EBEEFD;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.msgTextRight {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.msgTextLeft {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="messages" class="card-block">
   <p class="msgTextRight">hello Aditya</p>
   <p class="msgTextLeft">hello world</p>
   <p class="msgTextRight">i am varun</p>
   <p class="msgTextLeft">i am Aditya</p>
</div>
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. No need for floating here. Flex is a better responsive solution